# RestSharp "Not found" response

Tags: c#, rest, google-api, restsharp

I'm trying to use the Youtube Data API v3 with RestSharp. Problem is: I get the response: "Not found" when I try to send a request.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("key", my api key);
request.AddParameter("id", my channel id);
request.AddParameter("fields", "items/statistics/subscriberCount");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
this.BeginInvoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate () { label1.Text = response.Content; });
```

This seems to be a problem with RestSharp or the code because in the Google API explorer thing you can test out the inputs and it works there.

Comment: I think you are missing a "s". Try channels instead of channel.

Comment: Ok yeah I checked the explorer thing and it should have an 's' but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work means you still get 404 - NOT FOUND? If so, change Method.POST for Method.GET.

Comment: @NeoMossbäck did you [read the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) at all?  It very clearly shows that this is a GET request...

Comment: Thank you guys! I can't really remember what it said in the docs because I tried to work with APIs like a year ago or something and then gave up. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was trying the same thing today and was stuck on the same step. With an hour of effort I figured out.

In the `RestClient(baseUri)` constructor, just pass the base url and not the whole path.

While initializing `RestClient(resource, Method)`, pass the path as resource and method will be the second parameter.

Comment: This makes no sense. Do you mean "While initializing `RestRequest`" ???